# Crash after Device.StartTimer Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, asynchronous

I am switching between pages on my Xamarin app. From a list that updates every 10 seconds, to another form that checks a boolean every 250ms. Both run a Device.StartTimer, but shouldn't overlap.

This is the start timer on the List Form:

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        vm.cmdReload.Execute(null);

        //...

        blnTimerActive = true;
        startTimer();

    }
    private void startTimer()
    {
        Device.StartTimer(System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), () =>
        {
            if (!blnTimerActive)
                return false;
            UpdateUserDataAsync();
            return true;
        }); // This is where it breaks, I think..
    }
    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        blnTimerActive = false;
    }
```

Every time I try to run, it shows an error saying "No compatible code running on the thread" and "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A6Et.png)

This happens after I am on the next form and this one is "disappeared" I'm not sure why this timer is still running. Any help is much appreciated! Let me know if I can make this question any easier to understand.

Comment: first, use System.Timers, not Device.StartTimer.  Second, it you're getting an exception add some exception handling code (ie, try/catch) to catch the exception so you can see what is actually happening.  Third, it seems very likely the error is in `UpdateUserDataAsync`

Comment: Okay, I'll add some exception handling around UpdateUserDataAsync and see if anything pops up. I did try to add a try catch housing the Device.TimerStart with it crashing right inside it without going through the catch.. I'll get back to you on trying what you said.

Comment: You could add some breakpionts to find out what cause the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by double checking the output. It crashed in my code, but somehow didn't show where the break happened. I checked the output and it showed exactly where it was.

> If this is happening to you, check your output carefully. It should
> say what line number there was an error in, add a try catch, and step
> through. You should find your error easily that way.

thanks everyone for the help!